# Laravel routes error get request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Setting up a simple get request seems to throw a http error, this is my code so far:

**Link:**

```
<a href="{{ route('account.single', ['id' => $account->id]) }}">
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/admin/overview/{id}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@getSingle',
    'as' => 'account.single',
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'],
]);
```

Shows in the url as - `admin/overview?id=5`

**Controller:**

```
public function getSingle($id)
{
    return view('admin.account');
}
```

This is the error I get - `notFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

Note if I remove the `/overview/` from the route url so it displays as `/admin/{id}` it works but the get request doesn't find the id it finds the /overview/ from the url

Comment: Your URL should be `/admin/overview/5` not `/admin/overview?id=5`, that's probably why you're getting a 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in Jonathon's comment, the url for your route really should be being displayed as `/admin/overview/5` as you've intended and not `/admin/overview?id=5`.

---

To identify the problem you'll need to:

- Double check you're not seeing cached routes - in the command line run: `php artisan route:clear`
- Check through your routes to make sure you're not hitting another route further up your `routes.php` file e.g. `admin/{some_variable}`. You can use `php artisan route:list` to view the list of routes Laravel is looking for
- If you find another route that is causing an issue adjust the order in your `routes.php` file placing routes with greater specificity above routes with less specificity (example below).

---

```
Route::get('/admin/overview/{id}', [
    'uses'       => '\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@getSingle',
    'as'         => 'account.single',
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'],
]); 

Route::get('/admin/{some_variable}', [
    'uses'       => '\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@getSomething',
    'as'         => 'account.something',
    'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'],
]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Yours url is incorrect. You should build url like this:

/admin/overview/2

To do it use laravel helper function:

route('account.single', ['id' => 2])

Comment: That's exactly what OP is doing.